# How to assign different link page to different links?

Tags: jquery

Imagine I have four links in the page and for the first link: 'href' value should be 'one.html', for the second link: 'href' value should be 'two.html', for the third link: 'href' value should be 'three.html', and for the forth link: 'href' value should be 'four.html'

```
<a href="/mysite/">one</a>|
<a href="/mysite/">two</a>|
<a href="/mysite/">three</a>|
<a href="/mysite/">four</a>
```

So, the result would be this:

```
<a href="/mysite/one.html">one</a>|
<a href="/mysite/two.html">two</a>|
<a href="/mysite/three.html">three</a>|
<a href="/mysite/four.html">four</a>
```

Comment: And the code you tried that isn't working is where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the different values in an array and use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method like this:

```
$('a').attr('href',function(i,val){
    var arr = ['one','two','three','four'];
    return val + arr[i] + ".html";
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M3enS/)

Comment: makes no difference but isn't it unnoticably *better* not to iterate 4 times the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("a").attr('href', function(i, old) {
        return old + $(this).text() + ".html";
    });
});
```